A closed form for a Lauricella-like triple sum
There's a very beautiful identity that states
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n-1)!(m-1)!}{(n+m)!}\frac{4^{n+m}}{\binom{2n+2m}{n+m}}=8\rm G,\quad \text{where G denotes Catalan's constant}$$
I wanted to consider the following generalization of the above result
$$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n-1)!(m-1)!(k-1)!}{(n+m+k)!}\frac{4^{n+m+k}}{\binom{2n+2m+2k}{n+m+k}}\approx 1.92145$$
I could not arrive at a closed form expression but found many alternative integral representations.
I started by noticing the following identity is applicable here:
$$\frac{4^k}{\binom{2k}{k}} = \frac{k!}{(1/2)_k}$$
where $(1/2)_k=\frac{\Gamma(k+1/2)}{\Gamma(1/2)}$ is the Pochhammer symbol. This converts the sum into a Lauricella-type series
$$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma(n)\Gamma(m)\Gamma(k)\Gamma(1/2)}{\Gamma(n+m+k+1/2)}$$
We now use the following integral identity due to Dirichlet
$$\frac{\Gamma(\alpha_1)\Gamma(\alpha_2)\Gamma(\alpha_3)\Gamma(\alpha_4)}{\Gamma(\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3+\alpha_4)} = \int _{\Delta_3} x^{\alpha_1-1} y^{\alpha_2-1} z^{\alpha_3-1} (1-x-y-z)^{\alpha_4-1} \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z$$
where $\Delta_3$ is a three dimentional simplex. Therefore our sum is converted to the following integral over a tetrahedron:
$$\tag{1}S=\int_{x=0}^{1}\int_{y=0}^{1-x}\int_{z=0}^{1-x-y}\frac{1}{1-x}\frac{1}{1-y}\frac{1}{1-z}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x-y-z}}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z$$
After some tinkering we can convert $(1)$ to an integral over a unit interval:
$$\tag{2}S=-4\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-x)}{\sqrt{x}(2-x)}\arctan \left(\frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{x}}\right)\mathrm{d}x$$
After a trigonometric substitution, the integral becomes a  log-sine type integral:
$$\tag{3}S=-16\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\theta\cdot\sin\theta\cdot\log(\sin\theta)}{1+\sin^2 \theta}\mathrm{d}\theta$$
By expanding the geometric series we see that
$$\tag{4}S=-16 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \int_0^{\pi/2} \theta \sin^{2n+1} \log(\sin \theta)\mathrm{d}\theta$$
All such integrals seem to be of the form $a_n \rm G + b_n$, where $a_n,b_n$ are rational numbers. The sequence $a_n$ seems to be equal to $\frac{2^{2n+1}(n!)^2}{(2n+1)(2n)!}$. But I couldn't guess a closed form for $b_n$. Therefore $S$ seems to equal $-16(\rm G \sqrt{2} \operatorname{arsinh}(1) -M)$, where M is some mystery constant which is approximately $ 1.2618$
Also, from $(1)$, using the substitution $x\rightarrow u,~ y \rightarrow (1-u)v,~ z\rightarrow w(1-u)(1-v)$ we can convert the integral to range over the unit cube:
$$S=\\\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{(1-x)(1-y)}{(1-x+xy)\left(1-z(1-x)(1-y)\right)\sqrt{1-x-y+xy-z(1-x)(1-y)}}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z$$
But that seems far too unwieldy

Integrals Over a three dimentional simplex and Over a unit cube don't gives: 1.92145 ?

@MariuszIwaniuk, I apologize, I've found a typo in the unit cube expression. The simplex  expression on the other hand evaluates to the correct value on my Mathematica.

Perform tangent-half subsutition on the log-sine integral, one sees it is a multiple zeta value of level 12. In this case, it can be converted into an explicit sum of $\text{Li}_3$: https://i.sstatic.net/lnwVZX9F.png. Although a reduction in number of $\text{Li}_3$ is possible, the result is definitely not simple.

@pisco. This is still amazing! This Multiple Zeta Values package seems extremely useful too. If you would write this as a short answer, I would gladly accept it!
